# If statement in mysql query with inner join

Tags: mysql

I'm currently showing users that got unfinished jobs and based on the results I run a while loop and a switch case statement to come with the final results. I'm wondering if it is possible to move that statement in the mysql query.

```
select
    sum(cnt_jobs_unfinished = 0) cnt_users_no_unfinished_jobs,
    sum(cnt_jobs_unfinished_30d > 0) cnt_users_unfinished_30d,
    sum(cnt_jobs_unfinished_31_60d > 0) cnt_users_unfinished_31_60d,
    sum(cnt_jobs_unfinished_61_90d > 0) cnt_users_unfinished_61_90d,
    sum(cnt_jobs_unfinished_90d_more > 0) cnt_users_unfinished_90d_more
from (
     select 
        u.user_id,
        sum(l.job_id is null) cnt_jobs_unfinished,
        sum(l.job_id is null and j.date >= curdate() - interval 30 day) cnt_jobs_unfinished_30d,
        sum(
            l.job_id is null 
            and j.date < curdate() - interval 30 day
            and j.date >= curdate() - interval 60 day
        ) cnt_jobs_unfinished_31_60d,
        sum(
            l.job_id is null 
            and j.date < curdate() - interval 60 day
            and j.date >= curdate() - interval 90 day
        ) cnt_jobs_unfinished_61_90d,
        sum(
            l.job_id is null 
            and j.date < curdate() - interval 90 day
        ) cnt_jobs_unfinished_90d_more
    from users u
    inner join scheduled_jobs  j
        on  j.date <= curdate()
        and j.user_id = u.user_id
    left join last_update l
        on l.job_id = j.job_id
    group by u.user_id
) t
```

Here is the dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d2f217e074a391d8b5f769e08b1d2c87

As you can see because a user got both an unfinished job between 61-90 days and 90+ days the final table shows both results which is a mistake. The correct one would be 61-90 days: 0 users and 90+: 1 user.

Comment: so what you want to get is for each time range, the number of users having their oldest unfinished job in that range?

Comment: @Pepper Yes exactly. Thank you

Comment: What is the definition of an unfinished job?

Comment: @Strawberry from memory, based on one of OP's previous question, it is jobs without rows referencing them in the `last_update` table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f0eb480b6ba4301486297e3adbc88d9e)):

```
SELECT
    sum(IF(t.nb_days IS NULL OR t.nb_days <= 0, 1, 0)) cnt_users_no_unfinished_jobs,
    sum(IF(t.nb_days >  0 AND t.nb_days <= 30, 1, 0)) cnt_users_unfinished_30d,
    sum(IF(t.nb_days > 30 AND t.nb_days <= 60, 1, 0)) cnt_users_unfinished_31_60d,
    sum(IF(t.nb_days > 60 AND t.nb_days <= 90, 1, 0)) cnt_users_unfinished_61_90d,
    sum(IF(t.nb_days > 90, 1, 0)) cnt_users_unfinished_90d_more
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT j.user_id, DATEDIFF(curdate(), MIN(j.date)) AS nb_days
    FROM scheduled_jobs j
    LEFT JOIN last_update l
        ON l.job_id = j.job_id
    WHERE l.job_id IS NULL
    GROUP BY j.user_id
) AS t
    ON u.user_id = t.user_id
```

Instead of counting how many jobs are in each range for each user, I'm only looking at their oldest unfinished job, and extracting the number of days since the deadline: `DATEDIFF(curdate(), MIN(j.date)) AS nb_days`).

Then this result is `LEFT JOIN`-ed to `users` (that way, in case a user doesn't have any unfinished jobs, he'll still show up in the `cnt_users_no_unfinished_jobs` column by checking for `NULL` values)

Finally, it's just a matter of `SELECT`-ing how many `nb_days` are in each range.